# MPI Job crash with stack smashing detected

Tags: fortran, stack, mpi, centos7, amd-processor

I have a very small piece of MPI code in Fortran 90 that I found online to test my cluster with heterogeneous nodes.  The code likes like this
    program MPI

```
include "mpif.h"
integer :: myrank,size,ierr
integer :: resultlen
character (len=8) :: name 

call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myrank,ierr)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierr)
call mpi_get_processor_name(name, resultlen, ierr) 

write(*,*) "Processor ",myrank," of ",size,"on ",name,": Hello World!"

call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program
```

It was successfully compiled with the default mpif90 from the mpich package on CentOS 7.

```
> which mpif90
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif90

> mpif90 hello_mpi.f90 -o hello_mpi.exe
```

This code ran perfectly fine on one node.

```
> mpirun -host node1 -np 2 ./hello_mpi.exe 
 Processor            0  of            2 on node1: Hello World!
 Processor            1  of            2 on node1: Hello World!
>
```

But on the other node, it crashed every time. These two nodes are very similar in hardware (both AMD Opteron processors, 64-core vs 48-core, and memory size are different), but identical on the software side (both CentOS7 with exactly the same packages).  Here is what I got when running the code on node2

```
 > mpirun -host node2 -np 2 ./hello_mpi.exe
  Processor            0  of            2 on node2: Hello World!
  Processor            1  of            2 on node2: Hello World!
 *** stack smashing detected ***: ./hello_mpi.exe terminated
 ======= Backtrace: =========
 *** stack smashing detected ***: ./hello_mpi.exe terminated
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7fc61aee3597]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x7fc61aee3560]
 ./hello_mpi.exe[0x400e66]
 ./hello_mpi.exe[0x400bff]
 ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fc61adf6b15]
 ./hello_mpi.exe[0x400c31]
 ======= Memory map: ========
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7f394c8c3597]
 00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:2e 493967                             /home/user/tmp/hello_mpi.exe
 00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:2e 493967                             /home/user/tmp/hello_mpi.exe
 00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:2e 493967                             /home/user/tmp/hello_mpi.exe
 01e96000-01eb7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
 7fc61a395000-7fc61a3a1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7fc61a3a1000-7fc61a5a0000 ---p 0000c000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7fc61a5a0000-7fc61a5a1000 r--p 0000b000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7fc61a5a1000-7fc61a5a2000 rw-p 0000c000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7fc61a5a2000-7fc61a5a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61add5000-7fc61af8c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382897                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7fc61af8c000-7fc61b18c000 ---p 001b7000 fd:00 201382897                  /u/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x7f394c8c3560]
 ./hello_mpi.exe[0x400e66]
 ./hello_mpi.exe[0x400bff]
 sr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7fc61b18c000-7fc61b190000 r--p 001b7000 fd:00 201382897                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7fc61b190000-7fc61b192000 rw-p 001bb000 fd:00 201382897                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7fc61b192000-7fc61b197000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61b19d000-7fc61b1d8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7fc61b1d8000-7fc61b3d7000 ---p 0003b000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7fc61b3d7000-7fc61b3d8000 r--p 0003a000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7fc61b3d8000-7fc61b3d9000 rw-p 0003b000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7fc61b3dd000-7fc61b3f2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7fc61b3f2000-7fc61b5f1000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7fc61b5f1000-7fc61b5f2000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7fc61b5f2000-7fc61b5f3000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7fc61b5f5000-7fc61b6f6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7fc61b6f6000-7fc61b8f5000 ---p 00101000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7fc61b8f5000-7fc61b8f6000 r--p 00100000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7fc61b8f6000-7fc61b8f7000 rw-p 00101000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7fc61b8fd000-7fc61ba1c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7fc61ba1c000-7fc61bc1c000 ---p 0011f000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7fc61bc1c000-7fc61bc1d000 r--p 0011f000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7fc61bc1d000-7fc61bc1f000 rw-p 00120000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7fc61bc25000-7fc61bc3b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f394c7d6b15]
 ./hello_mpi.exe[0x400c31]
 ======= Memory map: ========
 7fc61bc3b000-7fc61be3b000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fc61be3b000-7fc61be3c000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fc61be3c000-7fc61be3d000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 7fc61be3d000-7fc61be41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61be45000-7fc61be4c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7fc61be4c000-7fc61c04b000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7fc61c04b000-7fc61c04c000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7fc61c04c000-7fc61c04d000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7fc61c04d000-7fc61c052000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c052000-7fc61c251000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c251000-7fc61c252000 r--p 00004000 fd:00 1362059600400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:2e 493967                             /home/user/tmp/hello_mpi.exe
 00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:2e 493967                             /home/user/tmp/hello_mpi.exe
 00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:2e 493967                             /home/user/tmp/hello_mpi.exe
 01ca0000-01cc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
 7f394bd75000-7f394bd81000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7f394bd81000-7f394bf80000 ---p 0000c000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7f394bf80000-7f394bf81000 r--p 0000b000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7f394bf81000-7f394bf82000 rw-p 0000c000 fd:00 201382493                  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
 7f394bf82000-7f394bf88000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f394c7b5000-7f394c96c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382897                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7f394c96c000-7f394cb6c000 ---p 001b7000 fd:00 201382897                  /u0                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c252000-7fc61c253000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c255000-7fc61c256000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c256000-7fc61c455000 ---p 00001000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c455000-7fc61c456000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c456000-7fc61c457000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7fc61c45d000-7fc61c67e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7fc61c67e000-7fc61c87d000 ---p 00221000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7fc61c87d000-7fc61c88a000 r--p 00220000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7fc61c88a000-7fc61c88f000 rw-p 0022d000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7fc61c88f000-7fc61c8c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61c8cd000-7fc61c8cf000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7fc61c8cf000-7fc61cace000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7fc61cace000-7fc61cacf000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7fc61cacf000-7fc61cad0000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7fc61cad5000-7fc61caf6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382890                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
 7fc61cce1000-7fc61cce5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61ccf5000-7fc61ccf6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61ccf6000-7fc61ccf7000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 201382890                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
 7fc61ccf7000-7fc61ccf8000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 201382890                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
 7fc61ccf8000-7fc61ccfa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fc61ccfa000-7fc61ccfd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00sr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7f394cb6c000-7f394cb70000 r--p 001b7000 fd:00 201382897                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7f394cb70000-7f394cb72000 rw-p 001bb000 fd:00 201382897                  /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
 7f394cb72000-7f394cb77000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f394cb7d000-7f394cbb8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7f394cbb8000-7f394cdb7000 ---p 0003b000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7f394cdb7000-7f394cdb8000 r--p 0003a000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7f394cdb8000-7f394cdb9000 rw-p 0003b000 fd:00 202328431                  /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
 7f394cdbd000-7f394cdd2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7f394cdd2000-7f394cfd1000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7f394cfd1000-7f394cfd2000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
  0 
 7ffcdf655000-7ffcdf676000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7ffcdf70d000-7ffcdf70f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
 7f394cfd2000-7f394cfd3000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 201326729                  /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
 7f394cfd5000-7f394d0d6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7f394d0d6000-7f394d2d5000 ---p 00101000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7f394d2d5000-7f394d2d6000 r--p 00100000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7f394d2d6000-7f394d2d7000 rw-p 00101000 fd:00 201382905                  /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
 7f394d2dd000-7f394d3fc000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7f394d3fc000-7f394d5fc000 ---p 0011f000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7f394d5fc000-7f394d5fd000 r--p 0011f000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7f394d5fd000-7f394d5ff000 rw-p 00120000 fd:00 202328443                  /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
 7f394d605000-7f394d61b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so

 Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

 Backtrace for this error:
 7f394d61b000-7f394d81b000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 7f394d81b000-7f394d81c000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 7f394d81c000-7f394d81d000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 201382505                  /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
 7f394d81d000-7f394d821000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f394d825000-7f394d82c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7f394d82c000-7f394da2b000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7f394da2b000-7f394da2c000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7f394da2c000-7f394da2d000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 201382510                  /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
 7f394da2d000-7f394da32000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7f394da32000-7f394dc31000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7f394dc31000-7f394dc32000 r--p 00004000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7f394dc32000-7f394dc33000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 136205960                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpl.so.1.0.0
 7f394dc35000-7f394dc36000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7f394dc36000-7f394de35000 ---p 00001000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7f394de35000-7f394de36000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7f394de36000-7f394de37000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 136205962                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libopa.so.1.0.0
 7f394de3d000-7f394e05e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7f394e05e000-7f394e25d000 ---p 00221000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7f394e25d000-7f394e26a000 r--p 00220000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7f394e26a000-7f394e26f000 rw-p 0022d000 fd:00 136205954                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpich.so.10.0.4
 7f394e26f000-7f394e2a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f394e2ad000-7f394e2af000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7f394e2af000-7f394e4ae000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7f394e4ae000-7f394e4af000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7f394e4af000-7f394e4b0000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 136205958                  /usr/lib64/mpich/lib/libmpichf90.so.10.0.4
 7f394e4b5000-7f394e4d6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201382890                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
 7f394e6ce000-7f394e6d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f394e6d6000-7f394e6d7000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 201382890                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
 7f394e6d7000-7f394e6d8000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 201382890                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
 7f394e6d8000-7f394e6da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fffabb37000-7fffabb58000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7fffabbed000-7fffabbef000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

 Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

 Backtrace for this error:
 #0  0x7FC61B916467
 #1  0x7FC61B916AAE
 #2  0x7FC61AE0A66F
 #3  0x7FC61AE0A5F7
 #4  0x7FC61AE0BCE7
 #0  0x7F394D2F6467
 #1  0x#5  0x7FC61AE4A326
 #6  0x7FC61AEE3596
 #7  0x7FC61AEE355F
 7F394D2F6AAE
 #2  0x7F394C7EA66F
 #3  0x7F394C7EA5F7
 #4  0x7F394C7EBCE7
 #5  0x7F394C82A326
 #6  0x7F394C8C3596
 #7  0x7F394C8C355F
 #8  0x400E65 in mpi at hello_mpi.f90:16
 #8  0x400E65 in mpi at hello_mpi.f90:16

 ===================================================================================
 =   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
 =   EXIT CODE: 6
 =   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
 =   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
 ===================================================================================
 YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)
 This typically refers to a problem with your application.
 Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

So my question is, what could be causing this problem?  The interesting thing is a similar piece of MPI code in C (shown below, obtained from the internet) worked just fine on both nodes without the above problem.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
// Initialize the MPI environment
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

// Get the number of processes
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

// Get the rank of the process
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

// Get the name of the processor
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int name_len;
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

// Print off a hello world message
printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d"
       " out of %d processors\n",
       processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

// Finalize the MPI environment.
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Could this be hardware related?  Or something else?

Comment: Your `name ` looks too short to me. Better to `usr mpi ` the `include ` is an old way before Fortran 90. It has itself been alreade superseded by `use mpi_f08`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is too short. The MPI specification states:

> The argument `name` must represent storage that is at least
>   `MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME` characters long. `MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME` may write up to this many characters into name.

If that does not fix the problem, then your MPI implementation might be broken.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yes, the following change fixed the issue      `character (len=20) :: name`

But the interesting thing is that the other node uses exactly the same packages, why didn't the problem show up on the other node?

Comment: `len=20` is **not** a proper solution. The string definition must be `character (len=MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME)` for the code to work with different combinations of MPI implementations, compilers, runtimes, etc. As to why it crashes on the second node, check the length of its hostname.

Comment: Thanks Hristo.  Will change that.  It appears the crash is related to the hostname. After I renamed the host, things all working fine, even with the old code.  Thanks.